# Dose the Apache Drill have any negative influence on the other members of Hadoop ecosystem in the existing Hadoop cluster?

Tags: sql, hadoop, olap, apache-drill, bigdata

if I deploy Apache Drill in a existing Hadoop cluster, dose the  Apache Drill have any negative influence on the other members of Hadoop ecosystem in the existing Hadoop cluster ?

Answer (score 1):

It wont have any negative impact on other members of ecosystem but it will hog a lot of memory of the node. Make sure you have enough memory before installing Drill.

Comment: Dose Apache Drill have any other minimum requirements for the hardware performance of the nodes in Hadoop cluster? Thank you very much！

Comment: Drill is not providing any minimum requirements on the cluster memory limits. Its all depends on the amount of data we're computing. Query plan in the drill shows that. You can even configure drill memory (https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-drill-memory/). In my usage & observation, Drill generally consumes lots of the CPU than the memory when you're computing large data set.

Comment: Thank you very much！( ^_^ )

Answer (score 0):

It's Hadoop compatibility component. The influence only happen if you don't provide enough resource for all the members to operate.

You can put Drill with HDFS in the same node or same cluster to get the best performance.